# Buttons not returned by subviews in Compact:Regular

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, subview, superview

I am writing an application for iOS. I have 3 buttons (of a custom UIButton subclass) in my view, each are added graphically through IB. I was running into a bug that I realized was coming from the fact that only one of the buttons' superview is self.view (where self is the ViewController). The other buttons belong to these things:

```
<_UILayoutGuide: 0x7f92d3d75d50; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f92d3d76070>>
```

I have absolutely no idea why they are being added to this subview instead of being direct subviews of self.view. While I could deal with the fact that they are not direct subviews with some extra code, I would like to know first why they aren't direct subviews.

EDIT:

I created an IBAction that gives the superview of the button when I click it, and when I click it, I get the view. However, when I try to look for the buttons in self.view.subviews, they're not there.

EDIT 2:

I have figured out that when the ViewController is in Any:Any, the subviews are returned just fine by self.view.subviews. If I switch it to Compact:Regular (which is what I need), all bets are off.

Comment: The frame is zero, so make it bigger in storyboard.

Comment: Make what bigger, the button?
They're each 191x71

Comment: The frame,you can try to move the button to the center of the view and try again, it might be misplaced.

Comment: What frame?
Two of the button's x values are -2, could that be it?
It was necessary because of some aesthetics with the border

Comment: How are you determining that the button's superview is the UILayoutGuide?

Comment: I have this method in the UIViewController:

        @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender : KeyRecognizeButton) {
        println("Superview:\(sender.superview)")
        println("Super-superview:\(sender.superview?.superview)")
    }

which prints layout thingy and then view for two out of the three buttons.

Comment: I would delete the 2 bad buttons, and add them again to your view in the storyboard. I don't know how you could add them to a layout guide -- I tried to do that, but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to not add them to the layout guide. I deleted the bad buttons and re-added them, still no dice.

Comment: Really odd thing, In the storyboard ViewController scene, they are both listed as being under the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the subviews from self.view in viewDidLayoutSubviews() function, which is called to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out its subviews.